# Increase Quantity If Product don't Exists yet In Cart

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

i want to be able to increase and decrease quantity item before submiting data to the cart
this is my increase and decrese methods they work fine already tested

```
public function decrease($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $panier = $user->panier;
    foreach ($panier->produits as $produit) {

        if ($produit->id == $id) {
            $qt = $produit->pivot->quantite;
            $qt--;
            if ($qt == 0) {
                $panier->produits()->detach($produit->id);
            } else {
                $panier->produits()->updateExistingPivot($produit->id, ['quantite' => $qt]);
            }
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}

public function increase($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $panier = $user->panier;

    foreach ($panier->produits as $produit) {

        if ($produit->id == $id) {
            $qt = $produit->pivot->quantite;
            $qt++;
            $panier->produits()->updateExistingPivot($produit->id, ['quantite' => $qt]);
        }
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

the probelem is in my blade i remove the comment from the input value it return this error `Attempt to read property "quatity" on null` i don't know what to do this is the third day already

```
<div class="quantity">
    <a href="{{route('decrQtePanier',['id'=> $prod->id])}}" class="quantity-button minus">
        <i class="klbth-icon-minus"></i>
    </a>
    <input value="{{--$prod->pivot->quatity--}}" name="cart[15945][qty]" type="text" id="quantity_61a9f089c4906" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="11" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric" />
    <a href="{{route('incrQtePanier',['id'=> $prod->id])}}" class="quantity-button plus">
        <i class="klbth-icon-plus"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<a style="text-decoration:none; " href="{{ url('add-to-cart/'.$prod->id) }}">
    <button style="border-radius: 50px; padding:0 20px; margin-left:40px" type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="352" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">
        Ajouter
    </button>
</a>
```

this is my cart module

```
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = ['user_id'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}

public function produits()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Produit','produits_paniers')
        ->withPivot('quantite');
}
```

and this is my product module

```
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'nom', 'prix', 'prixpromo', 'detals', 'image','categorie_id','user_id'
];

public function favories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Favorie');
}

public function paniers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Panier');
}

public function commandes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Commande');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Categorie','categorie_id');
}
```

this is my routes this operation i'm using is in the detail route i'm newbe and i'm really stuck in here

```
Route::get('/detail/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController@product_detail');
Route::get('/decreasePanier/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PanierController@decrease')->middleware('auth')->name("decrQtePanier");
Route::get('/increasePanier/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PanierController@increase')->middleware('auth')->name("incrQtePanier");
```

Comment: Well maybe just spell the property name correctly then? It says `value="{{--$prod->pivot->quatity--}}"` in your template, but `$qt = $produit->pivot->quantite;` in your PHP code.

Comment: You need to make sure the pivot exists before you try to read it. If the product has been detached, the pivot won't exist

Comment: no the probleme it's not with spelling the same code work fine shoppingcart page

Comment: @anyber can you show me how to do that i never did it befor in the panier module i have this already `public function produits()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Produit','produits_paniers')->withPivot('quantite');
    } `

Comment: you have to show how you are retrieving the data and passing it to your view